# Should we prevent square brackets in titles?

Tags: discussion, title

I've noticed an uptick in questions with square brackets in their titles such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093363/what-is-best-approach-for-angularjs-nested-ajax-calls-loop-within-a-loop) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093327/multiple-file-upload-with-jquery-removing-file-then-adding-it-again). When browsing a list of questions I automatically skip over those with square brackets as I'm used to seeing `[on hold]` or `[duplicate]`.

Might it be a good idea to prevent users having square brackets in titles, reserving them for specific site/moderating tags? Or am I being a too pedantic?

Comment: Against. That won't go well if the title includes array/dict indexing, e.g. *Why is `foo[bar]` undefined behavior here?*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Excellent point

Comment: You should have edited the square brackets out of those titles - round (normal) brackets would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already some title blocking mechanisms in place like: you cannot use the word *Problem* in the title. It can be added.

You might throw stones in the way for people who have questions about arrays, array syntax or [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c). You would have to be careful, how you match the offending square brackets and how you distinguish them from *good* square brackets. It will be hard or impossible to do.

Comment: Or Python. Or C. Or any number of programming languages that use square brackets in their syntax.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a fantastic point

Comment: Better list the programming languages that don't use square brackets....

Comment: @rene I've got whitespace. Can't think of anything else. ;)

Comment: @rene: How about Lisp?